# Show SQL ActiveRecord queries in rails console using SemanticLogger gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-semantic-logger

The `SemanticLogger v4.4.0` gem was added to the repository, and now when using the `rails console` all the `ActiveRecord` queries are gone:

before:

```
> MyModel.last
  MyModel Load (3.4ms)  SELECT  `my_models`.* FROM `my_models`  ORDER BY `my_models`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<MyModel:0x00007ff 
  id: ...
```

after:

```
> MyModel.last
=> #<MyModel:0x00007ff
  id: ...
```

I tried different setup flags for `SemanticLogger` but haven't found the one that returns the queries as before, and now is more complicated to detect poorly performance queries.

As a "partial-fix" I currently add it in a group and skipped `develop`:

```
gem 'rails_semantic_logger', group: %i[production qa]
```

This works on my local but I wish I could make it work on all environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the semantic_logger configuration but you should try

```
SemanticLogger.default_level = :trace
```

(you can run it in the console, and if works - add it to your initializers/development.rb or local.rb)

In my case I'd now see the output, but as a JSON:

```
> 2020-02-26 11:26:24.094050 D [2220:11016600] (220.0ms) ActiveRecord -- 
{ :sql => "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \"things\"" }
```

So I need to add in my local.rb (not sure how this can be done dynamically in the console)

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.rails_semantic_logger.semantic = false
end
```

to see

```
2020-02-26 11:31:34.972958 D [6280:14940580] ActiveRecord::Base --
    (198.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "things"
```

Answer (score 1):

`SemanticLogger.default_level = :trace` didn't help for me in console.

And I found this issue: https://github.com/reidmorrison/rails_semantic_logger/issues/83

Comment: you need to tail the log and is there, it not great, I ended up setting a env variable flag to enable/disable the gem on development

Comment: @zetacu I've added `config.semantic_logger.add_appender` to STDOUT, as described in the mentioned issue, inside `Rails.application.console do`. I can attach a code snippet to my answer if you want to, but it seems pretty simply.